# The property causeOf is not recognised by the schema for an object of type DDxElement

Tags: google, schema.org

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "MedicalCondition",
  "alternateName": "Mucus in Stool",
  "associatedAnatomy": {
    "@type": "AnatomicalStructure",
    "name": "Digestive System"
  },
  "differentialDiagnosis": {
    "@type": "DDxElement",
    "diagnosis": {
      "@type": "MedicalCondition",
      "name": "Blood test, Endoscopy, Colonoscopy,CT scan, Ultrasound and MRI scan"
    },
    "causeOf": [
      {
        "@type": "MedicalCause",
        "name": "Crohn’s disease"
      },
      {
        "@type": "MedicalCause",
        "name": "Ulcerative colitis"
      },
      {
        "@type": "MedicalCause",
        "name": "Irritable bowel syndrome"
      },
{
        "@type": "MedicalCause",
        "name": "Intestinal infection"
      },
{
        "@type": "MedicalCause",
        "name": "Food poisoning"
      },
{
        "@type": "MedicalCause",
        "name": "Colon or rectal cancer"
      },
{
        "@type": "MedicalCause",
        "name": "Malabsorption issues"
      },
{
        "@type": "MedicalCause",
        "name": "Proctitis"
      }
    ]
  },
  "possibleTreatment": [
    {
      "@type": "MedicalTherapy",
      "name": "Increasing the intake of fluid"
    },
    {
      "@type": "MedicalTherapy",
      "name": "Consuming foods rich in probiotics"
    },
    {
      "@type": "MedicalTherapy",
      "name": "Trying to have a nutritious balance of fiber, carbohydrates and fat"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

The above medical condition schema added is added in the website but it shows the error in Schema validator. The property causeOf is not recognised by the schema for an object of type DDxElement. I dont understand why? Please help.

Comment: What tool is giving you this error?

Comment: https://validator.schema.org/ is giving me this error